# How to generate a QR Code for an Android application?

Tags: java, android, qr-code

I need to create a qrcode in my android application, and I need a library or source code that lets me create a QR Code in an Android app.

The library I need must:

1. not leave a watermark (like `onbarcode` library)
2. not use web service API to create the qrcode (like Google's library zxing)
3. not need 3rd party installers (like QR Droid)

I already created such code for iPhone (Objective-C) but I need a quick fix for Android until I have time to make a QR Code generator of my own. It's my first android project so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you could use zxing its open source

Comment: zxing is not a web API, actually, see below

Comment: Try my simple test app for generating QR bitmap here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30529519/165071

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Have you looked into [ZXING](https://github.com/zxing/zxing)?
I've been using it successfully to create barcodes.
You can see a full working example in the [bitcoin application src](https://github.com/barmstrong/bitcoin-android/)

```
// this is a small sample use of the QRCodeEncoder class from zxing
try {
    // generate a 150x150 QR code
    Bitmap bm = encodeAsBitmap(barcode_content, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 150, 150);

    if(bm != null) {
        image_view.setImageBitmap(bm);
    }
} catch (WriterException e) { //eek }
```

Comment: I have forked the bitcoin open source from github and tryout on my android 2.2 devices, application force closed, anything wrong?

Comment: Sorry I haven't looked at that app for over a year. As mentioned below by Sean, checkout the source for the zxing encoder here: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk#trunk/core/src/com/google/zxing/qrcode/encoder

Comment: @Rob it will generate QR code of user defined number ? only number or number with laphabets

Comment: @Erum it will create a barcode for any most alpha numeric strings you provide

Comment: Use this: implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.13'

Answer (score 111):

with zxing this is my code for create QR

```
 QRCodeWriter writer = new QRCodeWriter();
    try {
        BitMatrix bitMatrix = writer.encode(content, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 512, 512);
        int width = bitMatrix.getWidth();
        int height = bitMatrix.getHeight();
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                bmp.setPixel(x, y, bitMatrix.get(x, y) ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE);
            }
        }
        ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_result_qr)).setImageBitmap(bmp);

    } catch (WriterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: @Stefano Can it generate n no. of unique QR code?

Comment: Worked like a charm g88!! +1
Is there any option in which I can add some logo to this?

Comment: How can i show a progress dialog while generating qr code ?

Comment: to avoid memory leaks, don't forget to [manage the bitmap memory](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/manage-memory) that is being created by `Bitmap.createBitmap`.

Comment: zxing asks to import the project, does it not have a dependency link to add to gradle file?

Comment: Use this: implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.13'

Comment: in this impl, can I put a icon in middle of QRCode?

Answer (score 52):

Maybe this old topic but i found this library is very helpful and easy to use

[QRGen](https://github.com/kenglxn/QRGen)

example for using it in android

```
 Bitmap myBitmap = QRCode.from("www.example.org").bitmap();
ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

Comment: .bitmap() is not found

Comment: You should use android dependency: 
`implementation 'com.github.kenglxn.QRGen:android:[version]'`

and import QRCode class like this:
`import net.glxn.qrgen.android.QRCode`

Comment: Failed to resolve: com.github.kenglxn.QRGen:android:2.6.0

Comment: In your project build.gradle add maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } to allprojects.repositiories

Answer (score 22):

Here is my simple and working function to generate a Bitmap!
I Use ZXing1.3.jar only!
I've also set Correction Level to High!

PS: x and y are reversed, it's normal, because bitMatrix reverse x and y. This code works perfectly with a square image.

```
public static Bitmap generateQrCode(String myCodeText) throws WriterException {
    Hashtable<EncodeHintType, ErrorCorrectionLevel> hintMap = new Hashtable<EncodeHintType, ErrorCorrectionLevel>();
    hintMap.put(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.H); // H = 30% damage

    QRCodeWriter qrCodeWriter = new QRCodeWriter();

    int size = 256;

    ByteMatrix bitMatrix = qrCodeWriter.encode(myCodeText,BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, size, size, hintMap);
    int width = bitMatrix.width();
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, width, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < width; y++) {
            bmp.setPixel(y, x, bitMatrix.get(x, y)==0 ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE);
        }
    }
    return bmp;
}
```

**EDIT**

It's faster to use bitmap.setPixels(...) with a pixel int array instead of bitmap.setPixel one by one:

```
        BitMatrix bitMatrix = writer.encode(inputValue, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, size, size);
        int width = bitMatrix.getWidth();
        int height = bitMatrix.getHeight();
        int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            int offset = y * width;
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                pixels[offset + x] = bitMatrix.get(x, y) ? BLACK : WHITE;
            }
        }

        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
```

Comment: This code works fine except that you have to include this (or higher) __implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'__ on the __dependencies__ at the __build.gradle(:app)__ and the object __writer.encode(...)__ needs to be __qrCodeWriter.encode(...)__ as was defined in the original non-edit; or change it to __writer__. I hope this adds some value.

Comment: IF you're generating a QR code for a thermal printer, use `Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888`.

Answer (score 13):

I used zxing-1.3 jar and I had to make some changes implementing code from other answers, so I will leave my solution for others. I did the following:

1) find zxing-1.3.jar, download it and add in properties (add external jar).

2) in my activity layout add ImageView and name it (in my example it was tnsd_iv_qr).

3) include code in my activity to create qr image (in this example I was creating QR for bitcoin payments):

```
    QRCodeWriter writer = new QRCodeWriter();
    ImageView tnsd_iv_qr = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.tnsd_iv_qr);
    try {
        ByteMatrix bitMatrix = writer.encode("bitcoin:"+btc_acc_adress+"?amount="+amountBTC, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 512, 512);
        int width = 512;
        int height = 512;
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                if (bitMatrix.get(x, y)==0)
                    bmp.setPixel(x, y, Color.BLACK);
                else
                    bmp.setPixel(x, y, Color.WHITE);
            }
        }
        tnsd_iv_qr.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    } catch (WriterException e) {
        //Log.e("QR ERROR", ""+e);

    }
```

If someone is wondering, variable "btc_acc_adress" is a String (with BTC adress), amountBTC is a double, with, of course, transaction amount.

Comment: Use this: implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.13'

Answer (score 5):

zxing does not (only) provide a web API; really, that is Google providing the API, from source code that was later open-sourced in the project.

As Rob says here you can use the [Java source code for the QR code encoder](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk#trunk/core/src/com/google/zxing/qrcode/encoder) to create a raw barcode and then render it as a Bitmap.

I can offer an easier way still. You can call Barcode Scanner by Intent to encode a barcode. You need just a few lines of code, and two classes from the project, under `android-integration`. The main one is [IntentIntegrator](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android-integration/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.java). Just call `shareText()`.

Comment: tanks this seems useful, only i'd hope to bypass any web API's, that might a bit unconfortable, in offline mode for my app, but this is very promising, i'll look into it

Comment: Not sure I was clear but I am saying that the zxing options do *not* involve any web APIs

Comment: Nope, it uses some libraries unavaile on android, like java.awt

Comment: Hello, sorry to necro this thread, I think it's better if I just asked a question here. I have the Barcode Scanner Application by you guys (I'm using it to scan a QR Code) and if I got this answer right, I could just do the same, open the Barcode Scanner via intent with different arguments and it would return a Bitmap QR Code for display?

Comment: @nivwusquorum, no, the encoder does not use `java.awt`, or connect to the web, and you can see it used in the Barcode Scanner application -- on Android, without an internet connection. @Razgriz no it does not return the image, but shows the image on screen for you. The user can save the image.

Comment: That's good enough for me. How do I call the Barcode Scanner via intent to show a QR Code?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent  The example shows scanning, but the class it refers to has a method to encode too.

Comment: I tried the following code, and I'm given a "Could not encode a barcode from the data provided." `Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.ENCODE");` `intent.setPackage("com.google.zxing.client.android");` `intent.putExtra("TEXT", "12321313231");` `startActivity(intent);`

Comment: Oh nevermind I fixed it. I used this: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

Comment: Last one. Is there a way to close the activity programmatically? For example, once the device displaying the QR Code gets a certain message (via bluetooth), it will close the activity showing the QR Code?

Comment: @Razgriz nope. Since the Activity showing the QR is outside of your app (it is actually the BarcodeScanner application) your app will have no control over it. By default on android all applications run "sandboxed" so that one cannot mess with another. It used to be possible to kill other applications, but the newer versions of android do not allow it.