# generate barcode and show on ImageView in android

Tags: android, barcode, barcode-printing

I am new in android development,and I'm working on android with eclipse now.

I want to generate barcode and show it in ImageView by clicking Button.

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=generate+barcode+and+show+on+ImageView+in+android&oq=generate+barcode+and+show+on+ImageView+in+android&aqs=chrome..69i57.232j0j1&client=ubuntu-browser&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: check this: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-create-a-barcode-reader--mobile-17162

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14207326/1937802

Answer (score 2):

Use zxing generate barcodes

Follow these steps and you are good to go.

first, locate core.jar under libs folder.

libs/core.jar
You can download ZXing-2.1.zip from here.

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/

After unzipping the file, find the jar file.

\ZXing-2.1\zxing-2.1\core\core.jar
And then write your own code like below.

```
import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.Map;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat;
import com.google.zxing.EncodeHintType;
import com.google.zxing.MultiFormatWriter;
import com.google.zxing.WriterException;
import com.google.zxing.common.BitMatrix;

public class BarcodeExampleActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(this);
    l.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    l.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    setContentView(l);

    // barcode data
    String barcode_data = "123456";

    // barcode image
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);

    try {

        bitmap = encodeAsBitmap(barcode_data, BarcodeFormat.CODE_128, 600, 300);
        iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    } catch (WriterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    l.addView(iv);

    //barcode text
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    tv.setText(barcode_data);

    l.addView(tv);

    }

    /**************************************************************
     * getting from com.google.zxing.client.android.encode.QRCodeEncoder
     * 
     * See the sites below
     * http://code.google.com/p/zxing/
     * http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/encode/EncodeActivity.java
     * http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/encode/QRCodeEncoder.java
     */

    private static final int WHITE = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    private static final int BLACK = 0xFF000000;

    Bitmap encodeAsBitmap(String contents, BarcodeFormat format, int img_width, int img_height) throws WriterException {
    String contentsToEncode = contents;
    if (contentsToEncode == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Map<EncodeHintType, Object> hints = null;
    String encoding = guessAppropriateEncoding(contentsToEncode);
    if (encoding != null) {
        hints = new EnumMap<EncodeHintType, Object>(EncodeHintType.class);
        hints.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, encoding);
    }
    MultiFormatWriter writer = new MultiFormatWriter();
    BitMatrix result;
    try {
        result = writer.encode(contentsToEncode, format, img_width, img_height, hints);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        // Unsupported format
        return null;
    }
    int width = result.getWidth();
    int height = result.getHeight();
    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        int offset = y * width;
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        pixels[offset + x] = result.get(x, y) ? BLACK : WHITE;
        }
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    return bitmap;
    }

    private static String guessAppropriateEncoding(CharSequence contents) {
    // Very crude at the moment
    for (int i = 0; i < contents.length(); i++) {
        if (contents.charAt(i) > 0xFF) {
        return "UTF-8";
        }
    }
    return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: can you paste your logcat?

Comment: Run your app on a device instead of an emulator so that you can see the scan functioning.

Comment: @MayankSaini , thanks to you , your code works well for me.