# Load image from barcode number in android

Tags: java, android

i m using scandit barcode scanner. this is my code..

```
// Enter your Scandit SDK App key here.
// Your Scandit SDK App key is available via your Scandit SDK web account.
public static final String sScanditSdkAppKey = "yUvPdFpQn3HJzGL5RM3b8AJdjiOFKWnv0bzITevNquI";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan);
    mHandler = new UIHandler(this);
    // We keep the screen on while the scanner is running.
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    // Initialize and start the bar code recognition.
    initializeAndStartBarcodeScanning();
}
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case SHOW_BARCODES:
                showSplash(createMessage((List<Barcode>)msg.obj));

                String code = barcodeText.getText().toString();
                Intent i = new Intent(Scan.this,ShowBarcode.class);
                i.putExtra("barcode",code);
                startActivity(i);

                break;
        }

    }

    private void showSplash(String msg) {
        Scan activity = mActivity.get();
        RelativeLayout layout = activity.mBarcodePicker;
        layout.removeView(activity.barcodeView);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 200);
        rParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        layout.addView(activity.barcodeView, rParams);
        activity.barcodeText.setText(msg);
        activity.addScanButton();
    }
}
```

}

i m passing that barcode to another activity...from that activity, i want to create(load) barcode image...is it possible to load barcode image from barcode number...?? if its possible, then how..?

Comment: You can use ZXing library for that. Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353392/generate-barcode-image-in-android-application).

Comment: thanks...its working well...