# how can add zxing library in android studio

Tags: java, android, zxing

I work with android studio to generate Linear Barcode, but I can not add the zxing library in my Gradle.

First I download this library and extract it, after that I copy jar file in that folder to app/ libs folder. Now I want to use this library's methods, but unfortunately I can't.

Please guide me.

Also, I need a download link for the correct library.

Comment: And what does this have to do with C#, PHP or C++? Please don't spam with irrelevant language tags.

Comment: please go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353392/generate-barcode-image-in-android-application