# Revert Barcode object to image in Android

Tags: android, google-play-services, barcode-scanner

I am getting `Barcode`(*com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode*) object from a physical sales card via camera. Is there a way to convert it back to a image using `gms:play-services-vision` library?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will get barcode value in a string. you may try to below code

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
tv.setText(bitmapstring);
tv.buildDrawingCache();
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
img.setImageBitmap(tv.getDrawingCache());
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there's no way of doing that by using the `play-services-vision` library. My first thought would be to take a screen capture of the preview of the camera before actually reading the barcode, but let's suppose you cannot do that.

If you have the actual data and the format of the barcode you can use [ZXing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) to generate back the barcode image.

Here's an example of how to do it: [Generate barcode image in Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353392/generate-barcode-image-in-android-application)