# How to create and show Qr Code in Android App

Tags: java, android, qr-code

can you help me please. I want to write small app for Android that has one button. When you push it it must show you qr code. Qr code must be generated form some string.

Tryed so far:

```
public void onClick(View v){ 
    QRCodeEncoder qrCodeEncoder = new QRCodeEncoder("Hello", 
        null, 
        Contents.Type.TEXT, 
        BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE.toString(), 
        smallerDimension); 
    Bitmap bitmap = qrCodeEncoder.encodeAsBitmap(); 
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code to show? Read up on Zebra Crossing (https://code.google.com/p/zxing/). You also don't specify what "some string" is

Comment: Look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800919/how-to-generate-a-qr-code-for-an-android-application

Comment: @Scott_Helme some string i mean that string can be stored in the body of the program, like final. I tried to do like this:
`public void onClick(View v){
     QRCodeEncoder qrCodeEncoder = new QRCodeEncoder("Hello", null,Contents.Type.TEXT,BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE.toString(),smallerDimension);
     Bitmap bitmap = qrCodeEncoder.encodeAsBitmap();    
    }`
And yes, i saw this site Zxing, but didn't find functions description that i can use in my program.
Thanks for answer))

Comment: @Seraphim thanks, i saw this question. the problem is that there is only small part of the code and my eclipse doesn't know function encodeAsBitmap from this example.

Comment: which library are you using

Comment: @Auto-Droid thanks a lot! Where can i find my email id?

Comment: @Ali4Android i used core-2.0.jar

Comment: oki then my post will not help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you will need to add zing2.1.jar file in your project then do the below code

QRCodeEncoder.java

```
public final class QRCodeEncoder {
    private static final int WHITE = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    private static final int BLACK = 0xFF000000;

    private int dimension = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    private String contents = null;
    private String displayContents = null;
    private String title = null;
    private BarcodeFormat format = null;
    private boolean encoded = false;

    public QRCodeEncoder(String data, Bundle bundle, String type, String format, int dimension) {
        this.dimension = dimension;
        encoded = encodeContents(data, bundle, type, format);
    }

    public String getContents() {
        return contents;
    }

    public String getDisplayContents() {
        return displayContents;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    private boolean encodeContents(String data, Bundle bundle, String type, String formatString) {
        // Default to QR_CODE if no format given.
        format = null;
        if (formatString != null) {
            try {
                format = BarcodeFormat.valueOf(formatString);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
                // Ignore it then
            }
        }
        if (format == null || format == BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE) {
            this.format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
            encodeQRCodeContents(data, bundle, type);
        } else if (data != null && data.length() > 0) {
            contents = data;
            displayContents = data;
            title = "Text";
        }
        return contents != null && contents.length() > 0;
    }

    private void encodeQRCodeContents(String data, Bundle bundle, String type) {
        if (type.equals(Contents.Type.TEXT)) {
            if (data != null && data.length() > 0) {
                contents = data;
                displayContents = data;
                title = "Text";
            }
        } else if (type.equals(Contents.Type.EMAIL)) {
            data = trim(data);
            if (data != null) {
                contents = "mailto:" + data;
                displayContents = data;
                title = "E-Mail";
            }
        } else if (type.equals(Contents.Type.PHONE)) {
            data = trim(data);
            if (data != null) {
                contents = "tel:" + data;
                displayContents = PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(data);
                title = "Phone";
            }
        } else if (type.equals(Contents.Type.SMS)) {
            data = trim(data);
            if (data != null) {
                contents = "sms:" + data;
                displayContents = PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(data);
                title = "SMS";
            }
        } else if (type.equals(Contents.Type.CONTACT)) {
            if (bundle != null) {
                StringBuilder newContents = new StringBuilder(100);
                StringBuilder newDisplayContents = new StringBuilder(100);

                newContents.append("MECARD:");

                String name = trim(bundle.getString(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME));
                if (name != null) {
                    newContents.append("N:").append(escapeMECARD(name)).append(';');
                    newDisplayContents.append(name);
                }

                String address = trim(bundle.getString(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.POSTAL));
                if (address != null) {
                    newContents.append("ADR:").append(escapeMECARD(address)).append(';');
                    newDisplayContents.append('\n').append(address);
                }

                Collection<String> uniquePhones = new HashSet<String>(Contents.PHONE_KEYS.length);
                for (int x = 0; x < Contents.PHONE_KEYS.length; x++) {
                    String phone = trim(bundle.getString(Contents.PHONE_KEYS[x]));
                    if (phone != null) {
                        uniquePhones.add(phone);
                    }
                }
                for (String phone : uniquePhones) {
                    newContents.append("TEL:").append(escapeMECARD(phone)).append(';');
                    newDisplayContents.append('\n').append(PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(phone));
                }

                Collection<String> uniqueEmails = new HashSet<String>(Contents.EMAIL_KEYS.length);
                for (int x = 0; x < Contents.EMAIL_KEYS.length; x++) {
                    String email = trim(bundle.getString(Contents.EMAIL_KEYS[x]));
                    if (email != null) {
                        uniqueEmails.add(email);
                    }
                }
                for (String email : uniqueEmails) {
                    newContents.append("EMAIL:").append(escapeMECARD(email)).append(';');
                    newDisplayContents.append('\n').append(email);
                }

                String url = trim(bundle.getString(Contents.URL_KEY));
                if (url != null) {
                    // escapeMECARD(url) -> wrong escape e.g. http\://zxing.google.com
                    newContents.append("URL:").append(url).append(';');
                    newDisplayContents.append('\n').append(url);
                }

                String note = trim(bundle.getString(Contents.NOTE_KEY));
                if (note != null) {
                    newContents.append("NOTE:").append(escapeMECARD(note)).append(';');
                    newDisplayContents.append('\n').append(note);
                }

                // Make sure we've encoded at least one field.
                if (newDisplayContents.length() > 0) {
                    newContents.append(';');
                    contents = newContents.toString();
                    displayContents = newDisplayContents.toString();
                    title = "Contact";
                } else {
                    contents = null;
                    displayContents = null;
                }

            }
        } else if (type.equals(Contents.Type.LOCATION)) {
            if (bundle != null) {
                // These must use Bundle.getFloat(), not getDouble(), it's part of the API.
                float latitude = bundle.getFloat("LAT", Float.MAX_VALUE);
                float longitude = bundle.getFloat("LONG", Float.MAX_VALUE);
                if (latitude != Float.MAX_VALUE && longitude != Float.MAX_VALUE) {
                    contents = "geo:" + latitude + ',' + longitude;
                    displayContents = latitude + "," + longitude;
                    title = "Location";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public Bitmap encodeAsBitmap() throws WriterException {
        if (!encoded) return null;

        Map<EncodeHintType, Object> hints = null;
        String encoding = guessAppropriateEncoding(contents);
        if (encoding != null) {
            hints = new EnumMap<EncodeHintType, Object>(EncodeHintType.class);
            hints.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, encoding);
        }
        MultiFormatWriter writer = new MultiFormatWriter();
        BitMatrix result = writer.encode(contents, format, dimension, dimension, hints);
        int width = result.getWidth();
        int height = result.getHeight();
        int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
        // All are 0, or black, by default
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            int offset = y * width;
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                pixels[offset + x] = result.get(x, y) ? BLACK : WHITE;
            }
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
        return bitmap;
    }

    private static String guessAppropriateEncoding(CharSequence contents) {
        // Very crude at the moment
        for (int i = 0; i < contents.length(); i++) {
            if (contents.charAt(i) > 0xFF) { return "UTF-8"; }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static String trim(String s) {
        if (s == null) { return null; }
        String result = s.trim();
        return result.length() == 0 ? null : result;
    }

    private static String escapeMECARD(String input) {
        if (input == null || (input.indexOf(':') < 0 && input.indexOf(';') < 0)) { return input; }
        int length = input.length();
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(length);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            char c = input.charAt(i);
            if (c == ':' || c == ';') {
                result.append('\\');
            }
            result.append(c);
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Contents.java

```
import android.provider.ContactsContract;

public final class Contents {
    private Contents() {
    }

    public static final class Type {

     // Plain text. Use Intent.putExtra(DATA, string). This can be used for URLs too, but string
     // must include "http://" or "https://".
        public static final String TEXT = "TEXT_TYPE";

        // An email type. Use Intent.putExtra(DATA, string) where string is the email address.
        public static final String EMAIL = "EMAIL_TYPE";

        // Use Intent.putExtra(DATA, string) where string is the phone number to call.
        public static final String PHONE = "PHONE_TYPE";

        // An SMS type. Use Intent.putExtra(DATA, string) where string is the number to SMS.
        public static final String SMS = "SMS_TYPE";


  //  A contact. Send a request to encode it as follows:
  //  <p/>
  //  import android.provider.Contacts;
  //  <p/>
  //  Intent intent = new Intent(Intents.Encode.ACTION); intent.putExtra(Intents.Encode.TYPE,
  //  CONTACT); Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); bundle.putString(Contacts.Intents.Insert.NAME,
  //  "Jenny"); bundle.putString(Contacts.Intents.Insert.PHONE, "8675309");
  //  bundle.putString(Contacts.Intents.Insert.EMAIL, "jenny@the80s.com");
  //  bundle.putString(Contacts.Intents.Insert.POSTAL, "123 Fake St. San Francisco, CA 94102");
  //  intent.putExtra(Intents.Encode.DATA, bundle);

        public static final String CONTACT = "CONTACT_TYPE";


  // A geographic location. Use as follows:
  // Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
  // bundle.putFloat("LAT", latitude);
  // bundle.putFloat("LONG", longitude);
  // intent.putExtra(Intents.Encode.DATA, bundle);

        public static final String LOCATION = "LOCATION_TYPE";

        private Type() {
        }
    }

    public static final String URL_KEY = "URL_KEY";

    public static final String NOTE_KEY = "NOTE_KEY";

    // When using Type.CONTACT, these arrays provide the keys for adding or retrieving multiple
    // phone numbers and addresses.
    public static final String[] PHONE_KEYS = {
            ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.SECONDARY_PHONE,
            ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.TERTIARY_PHONE
    };

    public static final String[] PHONE_TYPE_KEYS = {
            ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE_TYPE,
            ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.SECONDARY_PHONE_TYPE,
            ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.TERTIARY_PHONE_TYPE
    };

    public static final String[] EMAIL_KEYS = {
            ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL, ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.SECONDARY_EMAIL,
            ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.TERTIARY_EMAIL
    };

    public static final String[] EMAIL_TYPE_KEYS = {
            ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL_TYPE,
            ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.SECONDARY_EMAIL_TYPE,
            ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.TERTIARY_EMAIL_TYPE
    };
}
```

Do the below code to add string and set it to ImageView

```
String qrData = "Name : "+name+"\n Company : "+comp;
        int qrCodeDimention = 500;

        QRCodeEncoder qrCodeEncoder = new QRCodeEncoder(qrData, null,
                Contents.Type.TEXT, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE.toString(), qrCodeDimention);

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = qrCodeEncoder.encodeAsBitmap();
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (WriterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: can u tell me how can i encode contacts i m getting error

Answer (score 1):

I dont know which library are you using.
I am calling my zxing library QRReaderActivity in my app like this.

```
startActivity(QRReaderActivity.class);
```

the method is

```
private void startActivity(Class<?> className) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, className);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```