# Generate designer 2d QR code in android

Tags: android, qr-code

How to generate 2-d QR Code for some text and also having an image at centre in android ? I browse a lot but i found only how to generate simple 2-d QR code using ZXing library using this [link](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/09/android-generate-qr-code-using-zxing.html). Is it possible to generate 2-d QR Code having an image at center using ZXing library ?

Answer (score 9):

To center-align an image use code like in my [activity_main.xml](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/master/QREncoder/res/layout/activity_main.xml):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: app screenshot]

To generate and display a QR-encoded image use code like in my [MainActivity.java](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/master/QREncoder/src/de/afarber/qrencoder/MainActivity.java):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public final static int WHITE = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    public final static int BLACK = 0xFF000000;
    public final static int WIDTH = 400;
    public final static int HEIGHT = 400;
    public final static String STR = "A string to be encoded as QR code";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImage);
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = encodeAsBitmap(STR);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (WriterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    Bitmap encodeAsBitmap(String str) throws WriterException {
        BitMatrix result;
        try {
            result = new MultiFormatWriter().encode(str, 
                BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, WIDTH, HEIGHT, null);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
            // Unsupported format
            return null;
        }

        int w = result.getWidth();
        int h = result.getHeight();
        int[] pixels = new int[w * h];
        for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
            int offset = y * w;
            for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
                pixels[offset + x] = result.get(x, y) ? BLACK : WHITE;
            }
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

In **Android Studio** add the following line to `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    ....
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
}
```

Or - if still using **Eclipse with ADT plugin** add *core.jar* by ZXing to the *libs* subdir (here [fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtpR7.png)):

[image: Eclipse screenshot]

Comment: Alex, TS asked about in-QR image, not how to center an image

Comment: not me, but TS - talked about overlay image, here is a right idea https://github.com/wshychbydh/Qrcode

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use this [library](https://github.com/kenglxn/QRGen)

Thats how you can generate QR code with that

> Java

```
Bitmap myBitmap = QRCode.from("www.example.org").bitmap();
ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

> Kotlin

```
val qrImage = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.img_qr_code)
val myBitmap = QRCode.from("www.example.org").bitmap()
qrImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap)
```

Answer (score -1):

For whose ineteresting in the same, explore [this project](https://github.com/wshychbydh/Qrcode)

This is not a code of mine, but I've checked it and it works fine.

The main idea is in **QRCodeUtil**. It's just simple overlay. Unfortunately, no theory limitation provided.

```
    private static Bitmap addLogo(Bitmap src, Bitmap logo) {
    if (src == null) {
        return null;
    }

    if (logo == null) {
        return src;
    }

    //获取图片的宽高
    int srcWidth = src.getWidth();
    int srcHeight = src.getHeight();
    int logoWidth = logo.getWidth();
    int logoHeight = logo.getHeight();

    if (srcWidth == 0 || srcHeight == 0) {
        return null;
    }

    if (logoWidth == 0 || logoHeight == 0) {
        return src;
    }

    //logo大小为二维码整体大小的1/5
    float scaleFactor = srcWidth * 1.0f / 5 / logoWidth;
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(srcWidth, srcHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    try {
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);
        canvas.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, srcWidth / 2, srcHeight / 2);
        canvas.drawBitmap(logo, (srcWidth - logoWidth) / 2, (srcHeight - logoHeight) / 2, null);

        canvas.save(Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);
        canvas.restore();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        bitmap = null;
        e.getStackTrace();
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```