# how can I send audio file to generate qr code?

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing, audio-recording

I'm using the Zixing library in my android app and there is a feature that lets the user records audio then generate QR code for that audio. I don't know how to do it.

I assume the steps will be like this, but I'm not sure:

1. save the record at a cloud.
2. create QR code for the link above.

I'm using FireBase. A sample code or any reference is always appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.For cloud storage, check [this](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/storage) project.

You have to download .json file and also enable anonymous authentication from console to make it work.

You will be provided with an url after the file is uploaded.

2.For converting url to QR-Code, follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33727872/7360848)