# How do I send Qr codes info to Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm trying to store info from Qr code on Firebase. I want to store the Url that I get from the Qr code to Firebase. I get "No content provider:" and "could not locate file for uploading:" error in logcat. How do I add Content Provider So I can upload the file.

This is my code so far. I use Zxing for the Qr code.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {





        public void onClick(View v) {
            IntentIntegrator intentIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(
                    main.this
            );

            intentIntegrator.setPrompt("Scan Qr Code, for light use volume up and down");

            intentIntegrator.setBeepEnabled(false);

            intentIntegrator.setOrientationLocked(true);

            intentIntegrator.setCaptureActivity(Capture.class);

            intentIntegrator.initiateScan();


        }
    });

}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(result != null) {
        if(result.getContents() == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {

            String Contents = result.getContents();

            imageUri10 = Uri.parse(Contents);
      
            // Toast.makeText(this, Contents, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();




            uploadImageToFirebase5();
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}



private void uploadImageToFirebase5() {

    StorageReference fileRef = storageReference.child("profile7.jpg");
    fileRef.putFile(imageUri10);
}
```

Comment: Show the code where you are trying to save the url to firebase

Comment: The thing is that the url is save inside a IntentResult and I can't pass it to firebase. It needs to be an uri or string.  StorageReference dbb = storageReference.child("profile7.jpg");

        dbb.putFile(intentResult.getContents()); this wont work because intent Result is not an uri. But the string is inside the intentResult.

Comment: I did this but it does not add the url to firebase    storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();


        StorageReference dbb = storageReference.child("profile7.jpg");

        dbb.putFile(Uri.parse(intentResult.getContents()));

Comment: Tried this but not working String Send = intentResult.getContents();

        storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();


        StorageReference dbb = storageReference.child("profile7.jpg");

        dbb.putFile(Uri.parse(Send));

Comment: Updated my answer, try it and get back to me.

Comment: Now I did this: String Contents = result.getContents(); imageUri10 = Uri.parse(Contents); And it now gives me: "No content provider:" error in logcat.

Answer (score 0):

To get URI try this

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if(result != null) {
  if(result.getContents() == null) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   } else {
    //get uri here
       }
   } else {
         super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       }
   }
```

In the activity result.

Refer to this article on how to [read and write data to firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write). You can also read this [article](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Writing_Firebase_Realtime_Database_Data). If you have read, and attempted to write data to firebase then, you can post what you have done and you will be assisted.

Also suggest this solution, an [api built on top of zxing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33727872/11208036), makes things a lot simpler.

Comment: Thank you for the articles have read them but the issue is that I need to convert the IntentResult into string or uri to pass it into the firebase storage. I have tryied this but it wont work StorageReference dbb = storageReference.child("profile7.jpg"); dbb.putFile(intentResult.getContents());  intentResult is not an uri

Comment: I did this but the app scans the code but does nothing.                                           storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();


        StorageReference dbb = storageReference.child("profile7.jpg");

        dbb.putFile(Uri.parse(intentResult.getContents()));

Comment: Tried this but not working. String Send = intentResult.getContents();

        storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();


        StorageReference dbb = storageReference.child("profile7.jpg");

        dbb.putFile(Uri.parse(Send));

Comment: Oh, ok I thought you already had the url, and you just need to save. Let me update my answer

Comment: Hey Sabanto the YOUR_CODE does not seem to work

Comment: YOUR_CODE is your code, as in the code you passed startActivityforresult. If you didnt pass any value, remove the requestCode bit  in if statement

Comment: This is what I have now, now it just crashes.

Comment: Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        IntentResult intentResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(
                requestCode, resultCode, data
        );

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


            Uri uri = data.getData();

            StorageReference fileRef = storageReference.child("profile7.jpg");

            fileRef.putFile(imageUri1)

Comment: Check the logcat for why it crashed

Comment: Updated my answer try it

Comment: uri cannot be null

Comment: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=49374, result=-1, data=Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN flg=0x80000 (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.on/com.example.on.main}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: uri cannot be null

Comment: The uri is not getting the data

Comment: Now I did this: String Contents = result.getContents(); imageUri10 = Uri.parse(Contents); And it now gives me: "No content provider:" error in logcat.

Answer (score 0):

First add the dependencies to the project for Firestore:

```
api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:22.1.2'
```

Next access a Cloud Firestore instance from your Activity:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
```

You can save your data on Firebase Firestore like this:

```
Map<String, Object> myCode = new HashMap<>();
myCode .put("qr_url", "PUT THE QR CODE URL IN HERE");

db.collection("codes").document("PUT THE QR CODE DOCUMENT NAME HERE")
        .set(myCode)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Document successfully written!");
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Error writing document", e);
            }
        });
```

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for